# Performance of Memory Allocation, Multiple Threads and Various Allocation Size

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, openmp

I write an application which needs to create up to millions of objects per second. I found that memory allocation has a large impact on performance. Therefore I think about writing my own memory allocation, but I don't know if that makes sense.
My first step was to take a look at what's happening when allocating memory in multiple threads and different sizes.

My code:

```
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int64_t timestamp() {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>          (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

int main()
{
    static std::array<int, 6> threadcnt = { 1,2,4,8,16,32 };
    static std::array<int, 9> memsize = { 4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024 };

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw(8) << "B/T";
    for (int tc : threadcnt) std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw(8) << tc;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int ms : memsize) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw(8) << ms;

        for (int tc : threadcnt) {
            omp_set_num_threads(tc);

            int64_t start = timestamp();
#pragma omp parallel for
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) new char[ms];
            int64_t end = timestamp();

            float s = float(end - start) / 1000000000.;
            std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw(8) << std::setprecision(4) << s;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For every combination of threadcnt = { 1,2,4,8,16,32 } and memsize = { 4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024 } one million allocations are performed.

Compiling this with Visual C++ and running it under Windows 11 gives the following results (CPU:16Core/32Threads) in seconds:

```
 B/T       1       2       4       8      16      32
   4  0.0241  0.0129  0.0094  0.0041  0.0054  0.0063
   8  0.0256  0.0128  0.0070  0.0041  0.0049  0.0063
  16  0.0294  0.0152  0.0082  0.0055  0.0078  0.0091
  32  0.0333  0.0181  0.0101  0.0071  0.0108  0.0124
  64  0.0412  0.0233  0.0133  0.0105  0.0171  0.0183
 128  0.0584  0.0337  0.0204  0.0167  0.0267  0.0276
 256  0.0789  0.0469  0.0302  0.0347  0.0494  0.0479
 512  0.1229  0.0792  0.0566  0.0614  0.0972  0.0936
1024  0.2176  0.1508  0.1122  0.1105  0.1919  0.1842
```

Up to 8 threads performance increases, but then breaks down. Why is that the case? Has Windows problems with memory allocation for many threads?

And even more important: Why does time consumption dramatically increase with allocation size? I could understand this if memory would be initialized, but that shouldn't be the case.

Can someone clear this up? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I added a second parallelized for-loop for freeing the objects, and wrote a very simple (for my application specialized) memory manager. The results are as follows.

malloc()/free():

```
 B/T             1             2             4             8            16            32
      alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free
   4 0.0252 0.0150 0.0133 0.0082 0.0074 0.0058 0.0051 0.0050 0.0047 0.0068 0.0064 0.0096
   8 0.0261 0.0149 0.0133 0.0087 0.0072 0.0057 0.0055 0.0049 0.0043 0.0075 0.0053 0.0101
  16 0.0297 0.0208 0.0156 0.0117 0.0087 0.0081 0.0075 0.0073 0.0078 0.0081 0.0090 0.0116
  32 0.0373 0.0302 0.0199 0.0180 0.0112 0.0113 0.0104 0.0100 0.0112 0.0117 0.0121 0.0153
  64 0.0468 0.0408 0.0243 0.0220 0.0159 0.0146 0.0100 0.0111 0.0133 0.0132 0.0135 0.0172
 128 0.0624 0.0457 0.0359 0.0256 0.0232 0.0177 0.0164 0.0147 0.0207 0.0180 0.0198 0.0236
 256 0.0964 0.0614 0.0553 0.0376 0.0380 0.0268 0.0286 0.0251 0.0378 0.0310 0.0330 0.0423
 512 0.1349 0.1097 0.0943 0.0694 0.0657 0.0530 0.0528 0.0518 0.0698 0.0704 0.0656 0.0871
1024 0.2540 0.1464 0.1680 0.1077 0.1155 0.0835 0.0901 0.0928 0.1112 0.1286 0.1087 0.2174
```

custom memory manager:

```
 B/T             1             2             4             8            16            32
      alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free  alloc   free
   4 0.0187 0.0143 0.0101 0.0073 0.0060 0.0038 0.0042 0.0021 0.0043 0.0017 0.0040 0.0047
   8 0.0192 0.0145 0.0103 0.0073 0.0060 0.0038 0.0058 0.0061 0.0046 0.0077 0.0044 0.0043
  16 0.0193 0.0144 0.0101 0.0074 0.0061 0.0038 0.0058 0.0062 0.0050 0.0054 0.0048 0.0028
  32 0.0189 0.0146 0.0102 0.0073 0.0089 0.0077 0.0052 0.0057 0.0049 0.0039 0.0052 0.0041
  64 0.0192 0.0144 0.0100 0.0074 0.0059 0.0038 0.0050 0.0055 0.0044 0.0029 0.0040 0.0027
 128 0.0192 0.0143 0.0098 0.0073 0.0087 0.0103 0.0032 0.0021 0.0039 0.0043 0.0041 0.0028
 256 0.0196 0.0145 0.0169 0.0211 0.0056 0.0038 0.0046 0.0050 0.0040 0.0040 0.0041 0.0027
 512 0.0191 0.0144 0.0096 0.0073 0.0090 0.0103 0.0049 0.0053 0.0041 0.0033 0.0041 0.0027
1024 0.0189 0.0144 0.0164 0.0212 0.0056 0.0039 0.0032 0.0021 0.0039 0.0050 0.0040 0.0025
```

My conclusion is, it's worth to take a closer look if it makes sense to implement a custom memory manager.

Comment: This is a quite complex topic. First, allocations need to be synchronized and the overhead generally grows with the increasing number of threads. Second, heap implementations typically have some optimizations for small allocations. We once faced the same problem and resolved it with 3 techniques combined: 1) scalable memory allocators (tcmalloc, tbbmalloc, jemalloc,...), 2) small buffer optimization, 3) memory pooling. We don't know details about your application, so it's hard to tell what will work for you. (If you have a IEEE subscription, see https://doi.org/10.1109/TPDS.2019.2960514).

Comment: I'd expect a huge gain by allocating a huge chunk of memory upfront and then let each thread work on a part of it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That's exactly what the modern allocators such as jemalloc do!

Comment: @ciamej There are also native allocator mechanisms. Search for "pool allocators". C++ Weekly has an episode about it.

Comment: 1st problem: memory leak; you never `delete`d the `new`ed arrays. Write `std::make_unique<char[]>(ms)` instead. 2nd problem: you can test maximum available HW threads with `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`; that gives the number of virtual CPU cores. Software concurrency beyond that limit causes costly context switching - resulting in performance degradation. 3rd problem: optimized out unused pointer; Since you don't actually do anything complex with the allocated memory, aggressive optimization might totally remove it. Do some none-trivial tasks with the allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks, all. I check the libraries/solutions. @Red.Wave: Yes, that code has a memory leak, but it's only to demonstrate time dependenc, which is the same as in my real application. hardware_concurrency() returns 32.

Comment: @Red.Wave has a valid point. Even though "memory  leak" is not actually a problem in this experiment, you still maybe ought to think about freeing objects. If your application is only ever going to `new` a million objects up front, and then continue to re-use those same objects forever without ever deleting them, then maybe this experiment tells you all that you need to know. But, if you intend to _continualy_ `new` and `delete` millions of object, then you should be aware that `delete` actually can take longer than `new` takes. So, you might want to measure the `delete` time as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Solomon Slow. Depending on allocation size and thread count free() takes longer than malloc(). I added some data above.